# dialogflow: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN on paid plan

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have 2 dialogflow projects, I am an owner of one and a developer of another.

My own project works fine but not the another one. Both have same fulfilment code and setting. (Both have billing account, but not the same account, and on firebase's blaze plan)

here's my request

```
var options = {
            'method': 'GET',
            'hostname': 'www.someweb.pro',
            'path': '/api/v2/orders?terms=' + encodedParam,
            'headers': {
                'Authorization': 'Token token=' + token + ', email=' + email
            },
            'maxRedirects': 20
        };
```

Here's the log:

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN www.someweb.pro:443 at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup dns.js:67
```